# preg_match and preg_replace can't match pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following regex pattern to find part of a url :

```
$pattern = "(\d+)-.*";
//$pattern = "(\d+)-.*[.]htm.*";

$replacement = "/going/somewhere?$1";
$subject = "http://mudomain.com/59016-string.htm";
preg_match($pattern, $subject,$matches);
$final = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);

echo $final;
var_dump($matches);
```

The patterns should match

> 59016-string.htm

But all I get is null as output.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Edited:** ***after getting the solution***

For reference:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Comment: Use regex delimiters: `$pattern = '/(\d+)-.*/';`

Comment: @stribizhev damn.. how did I miss that. Can you write your comment as an answer. I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot about the regex delimiters:

```
$pattern = '/(\d+)-.*/';
```

In PHP, they are indispensible.
Also, note I am using single apostrophes: this is done on purpose so that we do not have to double the backslash with `\d`.